# How to prove that the inner product is positive unless $Ax = b$?

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra

[image]

Suppose $Ax =b$, then the equation above = $0$

Spp $Ax \neq b$, since $A$ is positive definite, then [image]

Am I going to the right direction for this proof? How can I show the rest is positive as well?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $r=Ae$, so $\langle r,e\rangle = \langle Ae,e\rangle$.

Comment: I know that r = Ae, but I don't know how to use that . Can you explain more please?

Comment: Added a bit more.

Comment: yes, I got <r,e>=e*Ae, if I expand more, it goes back to the same equation I had :(

Comment: $A$ is positive definite.  What can you say about $\langle Ae,e\rangle$?

Comment: Then its positive. Thank you so much . I didn't look at that way, I was thinking it has to be x*Ax